# Postgres 9.1.6 Error: index contains unexpected zero page at block 0

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have setup streaming replication on Postgres 9.1.6 running on a debian server and it's going on fine.

When I try to run a query on the replica DB I get the error below:

```
ERROR:  index "tbl_cust_id_idx" contains unexpected zero page at block 0
HINT:  Please REINDEX it.
```

What might be causing this error?